# How to delete a div inside a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have this HTML: 
body > div.main-page.bubble-element.Page > div.bubble-r-line > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.bubble-element.GroupItem.group-item.entry-1 > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div > **div**

How can I remove the last div using jQuery?

Comment: Please post your actual code, not pseudo-code.

Comment: This is not HTML (of course). It looks more like a giant CSS selector. Post your actual code.

Comment: You can use $("div").last().remove(), or you can add div and ID and then $("#id").remove()

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#id').remove()
```

Or if the **div** that you want to remove is inside another **div**:

```
$("#externalId").children("div[id=insideId]:last").remove();
```

> Where the `externalId` is the **div id** that has the **div** that you want to remove
>
> and the `insideId` is the **div** that you'll remove

Comment: Fade !== Remove

Comment: The code is correct and works, but we cannot say if it answers the question because there is only pseudocode

Comment: @ScottMarcus your right, in this case I'll only change the `fadeOut()`to `remove()`